# Run code exactly once before the Django runserver command

Tags: django

To be clear, i'm not talking exactly once each time the django server reloads.

I am aware that can be done using the `AppConfig.ready()` method

I tried overriding the management command, but even that won't work

```
from django.core.management.commands import runserver


class Command(runserver.Command):
    def handle(self, *fixture_labels, **options):
        print('I want this to get printed exactly once.')

        super().handle(*fixture_labels, **options)
```

Output -

```
$ python manage.py runserver
I want this to get printed exactly once.

I want this to get printed exactly once.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (1 silenced).
June 04, 2018 - 23:54:55
Django version 2.0.5, using settings 'quiz.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

I want this to get printed exactly once.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (1 silenced).
June 04, 2018 - 23:55:02
Django version 2.0.5, using settings 'quiz.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

There was also another iteration of above code that involved using the `call_command` to call `runserver`, but even that won't do the job.

**WHY?**

I want to start a webpack server, just before the runserver command, and exaclty once, meaning that it *doesn't run each time the server reloads*.

Comment: What exactly happens? It prints `'I want this to get printed exactly once.'` is printed multiple times?

Comment: Yup. Every time the server reloads.

Comment: See edit, i added the output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manage.py script is re-executed every time. You can run add both to a shell script and start them both simultaneously.